# Make-Your-Own-Markup Editor

Tags: gratis, web-apps, text-editor, markdown

**Many viewers; no votes. Please let me know what I can improve to make this upvote-worthy!**

I'm looking for a collaborative editor which would allow tweaks to be made to the markup language used. Something very similar to *Stackedit* or *Overleaf* (auto-compile between left and right windows), except I'd like to be able to add some of my own features not in any current markup language.

I'm hoping to collaborate with the rest of my family on documenting our collective memories before they are gone, however none of them are familiar with coding. So, like the editors above, the interface should also be developed enough that anyone could use it. The only difference being that I can futz with the way it's displayed.

*In case an example is helpful:
For instance, I'd like to add a feature which rates every story out of 5 stars. However the stars would represent how many people remember the event. So, inside a pair of brackets, one could list initials and it would be rendered as a list of `n` stars, where `n` is the length of the list.*

*Eg. `{AMHT}` --> ★★★★ or ★★★★☆*

P.S. Many editors like *Stackedit* and *Atom* allow for total configuration of snippets/shortcuts/display/theme with json/coffeescript/yaml but I haven't yet found one which allows configuration of the language itself.

**Logistics**: First priority is for it to be free. Second priority is that it should run in-browser on the web. However, downloading is not the end of the world. In that case, it should run on the latest versions of macOS, please. No preference whatsoever for the language in which the app is written.